# Dynamic HTML 5 menu does not work with postback

Tags: c#, html, menu, postback, pageload

I am generating **HTML 5** **Menu** using **ul** from Code behind in the pageload of master page. it is generating fine. but the problem occurring is in Post back. the dynamic contents of the menu disappears on postback. Pls let me know how to rerender the menu on postback.

Secondly I want to know why this problem does not occur if I use **ASP.net Menu**
Also pls let me know any other best practice for dynamic menu

```
 <ul runat="server" id ="Menu"></ul>
```

code behind:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        if (Session["user"] == null || Request.QueryString["applicationID"] == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid Session. Please login again!");
        }
        Application1 appRow = bal.GetApplication(ApplicationID)[0];
        PanelQuickJump.Visible = Boolean.Parse(Session["IsAdmin"].ToString()) && (TaskID == 9 || TaskID == 25 || TaskID == 33 || TaskID == 55) && (appRow.ApplicationClosed != true);            
        ImageButtonSearch.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open ('SearchPop.aspx',null,'scrollbars=yes, status= no, resizable = yes, toolbar=no,location=no,height = 700, width = 1200, left = 200, top= 200, screenx=10,screeny=600,menubar=no');");

        /* get task */
        activeTask = bal.GetActiveTask(ApplicationID, Employee.EmployeeID)[0];
        //applicant = employeeAdapter.GetApplicant(ApplicationID)[0];
        LabelTaskName.Text = activeTask.Task;
        /* get menu items */
        List<TaskForm1> taskForms = bal.GetTaskFormByTask(activeTask.TaskID, activeTask.SubTaskID);
            foreach (TaskForm1 row in taskForms)
        {
            li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
            anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
            string itemURL = row.Page + "?applicationID=" + ApplicationID;              
            if (row.Checkable == true)
            {
                string reqMenuItem = "<span style=\"color: #669900; font-weight: bold\">" + row.Title + "</span>";
                anchor.InnerText = reqMenuItem;
                anchor.Attributes.Add("href", itemURL);                                
            }
            else
            {
                anchor.Attributes.Add("href", itemURL);
                anchor.InnerText = row.Title ;
            }

            if (row.Page == CurrentPageName)
            {
                anchor.InnerText =  row.Title ;
            }
            li.Controls.Add(anchor);
            Menu.Controls.Add(li);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the only solution I found which solve my problem(render the page again on each postback)

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // if (IsPostBack)
//  {
//    return;
 // } 

   try    {         
if (Session["user"] == null || Request.QueryString["applicationID"] == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid Session. Please login again!");
    }
    Application1 appRow = bal.GetApplication(ApplicationID)[0];
    PanelQuickJump.Visible = Boolean.Parse(Session["IsAdmin"].ToString()) && (TaskID == 9 || TaskID == 25 || TaskID == 33 || TaskID == 55) && (appRow.ApplicationClosed != true);            
    ImageButtonSearch.Attributes.Add("onclick", "window.open ('SearchPop.aspx',null,'scrollbars=yes, status= no, resizable = yes, toolbar=no,location=no,height = 700, width = 1200, left = 200, top= 200, screenx=10,screeny=600,menubar=no');");

    /* get task */
    activeTask = bal.GetActiveTask(ApplicationID, Employee.EmployeeID)[0];
    //applicant = employeeAdapter.GetApplicant(ApplicationID)[0];
    LabelTaskName.Text = activeTask.Task;
    /* get menu items */
    List<TaskForm1> taskForms = bal.GetTaskFormByTask(activeTask.TaskID, activeTask.SubTaskID);
        foreach (TaskForm1 row in taskForms)
    {
        li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        anchor = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
        string itemURL = row.Page + "?applicationID=" + ApplicationID;              
        if (row.Checkable == true)
        {
            string reqMenuItem = "<span style=\"color: #669900; font-weight: bold\">" + row.Title + "</span>";
            anchor.InnerText = reqMenuItem;
            anchor.Attributes.Add("href", itemURL);                                
        }
        else
        {
            anchor.Attributes.Add("href", itemURL);
            anchor.InnerText = row.Title ;
        }

        if (row.Page == CurrentPageName)
        {
            anchor.InnerText =  row.Title ;
        }
        li.Controls.Add(anchor);
        Menu.Controls.Add(li);
 }
}
```